# Mock and test websocket using the ws module with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a module that connects to a websocket API as a client. It looks like follows:

> **./src/utils/connect-realtime-api.js**
>
> ```
> const WebSocket = require('ws')
> const setup = require('./helpers/setup')
>
> connectRealtimeAPI = () => {
>     const ws = new WebSocket('wss //echo.websocket.org')
>
>     ws.onopen = () => {
>         ws.send(JSON.stringify({ "type": "reg", "channel": "stats1" }))
>         ws.send(JSON.stringify({ "type": "reg", "channel": "stats2" }))
>         console.log('[WebSocket] Connection opened.')
>     }
>
>     ws.onerror = (event) => {
>         console.error('[WebSocket] An error occurred.')
>         console.error(`Code: ${event.code}`)
>         console.error(`Reason: ${event.reason}`)
>     }
>
>     ws.onclose = (event) => {
>         console.error('[Websocket] Connection closed.')
>         console.error(`Code: ${event.code}`)
>         console.error(`Reason: ${event.reason}`)
>         console.log('Retrying connection in 10 seconds...')
>         setTimeout(() => connectRealtimeAPI(), 10000)
>     }
>
>     setup(ws)
> }
>
> module.exports = connectRealtimeAPI
> ```

The `setup` function accept `ws` as a parameter and then performs some actions based on the messages that it receives.

> **./src/utils/helpers/setup.js**
>
> ```
> const setup = (ws) => {
>   ws.onmessage = (event) => {
>       data = JSON.parse(event.data)
>
>       // Perform actions based on order in which messages are received.
>   }
> }
>
> module.exports = setup
> ```

I want to test `connect-realtime-api.js` as well as `setup.js` using Jest.

To achieve this, I would have to mock the `ws` library with Jest by placing `ws.js` within the `__mocks__` directory and find a way to send `open`, `error`, `close` as well as messages via the mocked `ws` to trigger the appropriate `console.logs` and `console.errors` and then test against them.

I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-socket) library which might help me achieve this but am unable to figure out how to go about doing it. There is also an implementation clue given [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-websocket-mock#using-jest-websocket-mock-to-interact-with-a-non-global-websocket-object) but again I am unable to figure out how to send events/messages once `ws` has been mocked successfully.

Looking for help regarding the implementation details for the tests.

Comment: Interested in knowing if you ever came to a good solution @philosipher.

Comment: Hey, I actually didn't end up testing it but there is a library that allows you to do it easily now. Just googling should help you find it!